# Exporting a module based of a js file - without changing the original file

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I have a .js file, let's say `original.js`:

```
var a = function(){};
var b = "something";
```

I exported its' content, in order to be able to use it in a Typescript component:

```
//Original file content:
var a = function(){};
var b = "something";
//My addition:
var MyModule = {a : a, b : b};
export { MyModule };
```

But I want all the module-related code to be stored in a different file - and keep `original.js` untouched. Then I want to import the new file instead of the `original` file.

The idea is to take and old 3rd party `.js` file and make it importable.

**EDIT**

I came to realisation that the keyboard I was looking for is `declare` instead of `export`. I have created a `original.d.ts` file, looking like that:

```
declare var a : Function;
declare var b : string;
```

Which enables me to import it as following:

```
import 'src/original';
```

However, there are two problem with this solution:

1. I really wanted to give an alias to `original` since `a` and `b` could be confusing without their context, but now when it has declared members and no exports, I cannot do that (`import * as Original from 'src/original'` would say that this is not a module).
2. I have to explicitly declare each and every variable/function out of `original.js`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Export the module from here;
Make a new file (i.e: index.js)
Import the module into `index.js`

`import Module1 from './Module1.js'`

export them by using

```
export { Module1, Module2, ... , Modulen };
```

Comment: In order to `import`, I need to `export` from the original file. I do not want to change the original file.